# Java connect to FMS

Tags: java, actionscript-3, jsp, flash-media-server

#### My scenario:

I'm using `JSP` and `FMS(Flash Media Server)` to build a live chat room.

I create a **liverooms** folder in `fms_insatall_dir/applications/`, so my **Application** name is `liverooms`.

#### My demands:

I need multi rooms with different names(that is multi `instances` in `liverooms` application in FMS term)

Actually I need to generate names of rooms dynamically in my Java code.

#### My problems:

Can I connect to FMS via Java? If ok how can I send `add instance` messages dynamically to FMS?

I know **ActionScript** can do this, if I can't use java, then how to use ActionScript in a JSP page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thx!

Comment: does that FMS thing have any API, library,...?

Comment: @user5266804 FMS is Flash Media Server by Adobe. I'm looking for some library too...

Comment: It must have some library(probably native), so just load them using JNA or JNI and do the work.

Comment: @user5266804 thx. I'm also trying to use ActionScritp... It seems use AS is better.

Comment: @xring I don't know about Java, but I know that using ActionScript (an swf in your page ) you can communicate with FMS ( now AMS : Adobe Media Server ) which has its [ActionScript server-side APIs](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/ssaslr/topics/server-side-actionscript-language-reference.html). More details about the [Server-Side ActionScript for AMS 5.0.1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/ssaslr/adobemediaserver_5.0.1_sslr.pdf)  (pdf) ...

Comment: The problem is the FLash thing, it's kinda deprecated, sooner or later more companies and applications will deprecate it, just like firefox did. Just wonder why don't you utilize pure and much better web solutions? websocket? ,....

Comment: @akmozo does this mean: I write some AS codes and compile then to a abc.swf file, then I can embed this abc.swf file in my page (jsp or php or somethig else), and when I visit this page embeded in abc.swf I can got communication with AMS? thx!

Comment: @user5266804 thanks a lot. Actually I'm setting up a prototype, I got input streams with **.flv** format from client, transfer streams to my SMS (streaming media server), then users can got these streams via browser. I know that Flash is kinda deprecated, I'm just trying on it. I'll try some other solutions later. Thanks for your patient and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect from FMS to a running Java app using BlazeDS, using a server-side-ActionScript NetConnection, like so:

```
blaze_nc = new NetConnection(); 
blaze_nc.connect("http://my.url/messagebroker/streamingamf");
```

This assumes you configured your servlet container to redirect this type of request correctly. See example [here](https://github.com/apache/flex-blazeds/blob/master/apps/blazeds/WEB-INF/web.xml).

You may read through the richly-documented [sample services-config.xml file](https://github.com/apache/flex-blazeds/blob/master/resources/config/services-config.xml) in order to learn more about the various modes in which BlazeDS can be configured to work. I've been using it in "remoting" mode, but "messaging" seems like a better fit for your use-case.